# How to check if a method returns an error or a value?

Tags: c++

I have a method in my class let us name it X method, that returns error an if some conditions are not satisfied, otherwise it returns a pointer.My question is this, I want to use this method in another class but it is a bit confusing.I want assign this returning pointer to another pointer.But how can I check that this method returns an error or a pointer?

Comment: It throws an exception. It doesn't return it. Use a `catch` block.

Comment: Get the pointer that is returned by assignment `ret = f()`. Exceptions are passed up the call stack with another mechanism which requires a try-catch block.

Comment: Your edit changed the whole question. Please show us the function signature of `X`. How does it return two different types?

Answer (score 1):

It throws an exception. It doesn't return it. Use a catch block.

```
void *p = nullptr;
try {
  p = X();
} catch(...) {
  std::cerr << "Call failed\n";
  // assign a default value
  // p = defaultValue;

  // rethrow if necessary
  // throw;

  // return the function
  // return;
}
void *anotherPtr = p;
```

You have many options how to handle it.

Comment: Maybe this should read, "should throw an exception" not "it throws an exception." The OP may very well be returning the error.

Answer (score 0):

If the pointer is expected to always be non-null on success, then simply return null on failure.  The caller can check for that.